# How can I keep leading zeros in a column, when I export to CSV?

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I am trying to export a dataframe with a column with leading zeros like this:

```
df["CD_LIN_NEG"]

0     001
1     001
2     004
3     001
4     001
5     001
6     003
7     006
Name: CD_LIN_NEG, dtype: object
```

But when I export to csv, all of the leading zeros are cut off any numbers when I open the file in Excel. How can I keep the zeros?

I have tried to convert to string but it doesn't work:

```
df["CD_LIN_NEG"] = df['T_PROD_CP.LN'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.zfill(3))
```

or in this way:

```
df["CD_LIN_NEG"] = '00' + df['T_PROD_CP.LN'].astype(str)
```

Comment: This looks like an excel issue, pandas will preserve the leading zeroes, you can check the csv, change the display formatting in excel

Comment: This is an excel issue. If you open your file in notepad you will see that leading zeroes are there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is an excel problem as @EdChum suggested.  You'll want to wrap your column in `=""` with `apply('="{}".format)`.  This will tell excel to treat the entry as a formula that returns the text within quotes.  That text will be your values with leading zeros.

Consider the following example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['001', '002']))
df.A = df.A.apply('="{}"'.format)
df.to_excel('test_leading_zeros.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 6):

This may not be directly relevant to the question but if the data is read from external sources via `pandas.read_csv()` or `pandas.read_excel()`, then we could specify `converters` for relevant columns using `str`.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(
    './myexcel.xlsx',
    converters={
        "serialno": str, # Ensure serialno is read as string, maintaining leading 0's
        "location": lambda x: '-' if x=='' else str(x),
    }

df1 = pd.read_excel(
    './mycsv.csv',
    converters={
        "serialno": str, # Ensure serialno is read as string, maintaining leading 0's
        "location": lambda x: '-' if x=='' else str(x),
    }
```

When the data is saved to Excel or CSV files, the leading 0's are maintained.

Answer (score 5):

The most simple solution is to just add `dtype=str` while reading `txt` or `csv` file in Pandas:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\my_folder\my_file.csv', dtype=str)
```

Comment: Adding dtype=str worked for pd.read_excel() also in my case.