# Python: Keep leading zeroes when converting from excel to CSV with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I have an excel sheet that is to be inserted into a database. I wrote a python script, which takes an excel file, converts it into a CSV and then inserts it to the database. The problem is that the excel sheet contains zipcodes, which unfortunately removes the leading zeroes.

Here is my code that reads the excel sheet and puts it into a csv:

```
def excel_to_csv():
    xlsx = pd.read_excel(excel_path + fileName + '.xlsx')
    xlsx.to_csv(csv_file, encoding='utf-8', index=False, na_rep=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)


excel_to_csv()
```

And then I use this code to insert it into the database:

```
with open(csv_file, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        cur.execute(
            "INSERT INTO table (foo1, foo2, zipcode, foo3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s); ",
            row
        )

conn.commit()
```

When I print out my csv after its converted from excel, I get this result:

```
foo1,foo2,zipcode,foo3
353453452,DATA,37,CITY
463464356,DATA,2364,CITY
```

The zipcode cell in the excel file is converted into text so it keeps the leading zeroes, but how can I keep the leading zeroes when I convert the excel file into csv?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

> **dtype** : Type name or dict of column -> type, default None
>   Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32} Use object to preserve data as stored in Excel and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.
>   New in version 0.20.0.

So you can tell `pd.read_excel` to not interpret the data by setting the `dtype`-kwarg to `object`:

```
xlsx = pd.read_excel(excel_path + fileName + '.xlsx', dtype='object')
```

Comment: No luck, it's still written as "37" instead of "0037" into the csv

Comment: I had to reformat the cell which included the zipcode! I thought it was set to text, but after testing i had apparently changed it to zipcode in excel. I formatted it back and now everything seems right! Thanks for your help @SpghttCd !

Comment: I hope the solution may be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240535/how-can-i-keep-leading-zeros-in-a-column-when-i-export-to-csv/56660495#56660495