# pandas write and read in column and keep leading 0

Tags: python, pandas

While trying to write a Pandas  dataframe to csv and read from csv, one column is   of number string with leading zeros.
Tried different method to write to csv to keep the leading zeros, this one works well while writing to csv
[How can I keep leading zeros in a column, when I export to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240535/how-can-i-keep-leading-zeros-in-a-column-when-i-export-to-csv)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['001', '002']))
df.A = df.A.apply('="{}"'.format)
df.to_excel('test_leading_zeros.xlsx')
```

But when read back from csv, my dataframe column looks like:

```
A
="001"
="002
.....
```

How to read this back right?

Comment: Based on @Sayandip Dutta's answer, next will write to csv with correct format. Based on current error. End up using df.A.str.extract('(\d+)')  to only extract numbers.

Comment: Values with leading zeros are not numbers, they are strings. However, without direction a numeric column with leading 0, will be interpreted as int or float and the 0s will be dropped. Therefore you must specify the `dtype` when reading the file. `pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype={'A': str})`